# OpenCV (or similar library) in Go

Tags: c++, opencv, go, computer-vision

I intend to use OpenCV for a project in which I've already built the server in Go. However, OpenCV doesn't have a Go API, so what's the best solution? Call a c++ program with `.exec`, use swig, find another library to do computer vision?

Thanks.

Edit: I want to maximize performance, and I'm ok with C++.

Comment: I've specified that my #1 requirement is performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SWIG](http://zacg.github.io/blog/2013/06/06/calling-c-plus-plus-code-from-go-with-swig/) is certainly a viable option.

You can also search for a Go binding to OpenCV.  For example: https://github.com/lazywei/go-opencv

Comment: But would you say it's the most performant option?